# Determining whether VBA is necessary in Excel, or if a pivot chart/table can suffice

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I wish that I had a more precisely descriptive title for this question, but I am not very knowledgeable with Excel spreadsheets or VBA (I'm primarily a Java developer, and don't play much in the Microsoft world).

I'm trying to use an Excel spreadsheet to accomplish something.  I need to determine whether I can get there with a PivotTable, PivotChart, or some other built-in functionality... or whether I need to go down the path of writing custom VBA code (or maybe using another platform altogether).

The purpose of the spreadsheet is to help create schedules for an organization (a Toastmasters club).  This organization has a roster of members, it meets weekly, and various members are assigned to various roles in a given meeting.

My spreadsheet looks like this:

### First Tab

One column... a list of names representing the membership roster.

### Second Tab

Each row represents a past meeting date.  There are columns for each role, and the cells are to be populated with who served that role on that date.  I use Data Validation to have the first tab's roster available inside each cell as a pulldown.

### Third Tab (maybe multiple tabs?)

Here's the point of the whole thing.  For each of the possible meeting roles, I would like to see which members are the most "overdue" to be assigned for that role.  Basically, I want a list of all the club members, sorted in order of how long it's been since they last served that role.  People who have *never* served in that role would be sorted at the top of the list.

Is that third tab data something that can be accomplished with a PivotTable, etc... or am I misunderstanding the purposes and limitations of those tools?

Comment: Steve - check your email, I've sent you my demo file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first instinct is to move you to Access where you can SQL query to your heart's content, but I'm sure this can be done in Access without any custom coding.

1. PivotTables may work, but I avoid them for several reasons (hard to describe to casual users, doesn't update automatically, hard to format, etc.), so here is something using just Excel's built-in cell functions.
2. Check out **vlookup()** and **countif()** on http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index.php.  (The built-in help files work too.  I just like this site more)
3. In the image below, I have simulated your **Tab2** and **Tab3**.  **Tab2** is purely data with no equations.  **Vlookup()** *requires* that this table be sorted by Date Descending and with the date column on the far right.
4. **Tab3** counts both the # times each person has served in that role and when they last worked that position.
5. The formula in cell C13 is `=COUNTIF($B3:$B8,$B13)`. i.e. it counts the number of times that "Abe" appears in the Chairperson column of Tab2.
6. The formula in cell D13 is `=IF(C13>0,VLOOKUP($B13,$B$2:$D$8,3,FALSE),"-")`.  i.e. if that person ever served in that role, then it finds the most recent date.
7. The formulas for security are almost the same.  The "Last Served" column is now `=IF(E13>0,VLOOKUP($B13,$C$2:$D$8,2,FALSE),"-")`.  The ranges need to be renamed here to satisfy the needs of the **Vlookup** function (a SQL query would be really convenient here, but Excel doesn't allow that)
8. It's hard to define if someone is 'overdue' because some people will argue that "Last Served" is more important than the "# Times Served" and others will argue the exact opposite.  I suggest looking at both columns and just talking it over.
   [image: Sample Image]

Comment: @PowerUser:  Thank you very much!  There is a bit more complexity that I omitted for ease of explanation... but with that formula reference page, I've been able to figure out the next steps on my own.

Comment: @PowerUser:  One question, though.  If I have to put my Date field on the far-right in that first table, can I do something comparable to a "Freeze Panes" in reverse?  That is, some means of keeping that right-most column in view at all times while scrolling horizontally through the other columns?

Comment: @PowerUser:  Ah, wait.  Couldn't I actually just swap the VLOOKUP formula for the regular LOOKUP formula... using the member's name for the 1st parameter, the role column for the 2nd parameter, and the Date column for the 3rd parameter?  I know that the 2nd parameter is supposed to be sorted, but here they actually *are*... just sorted by date rather than by name.

Comment: I suppose you can use Lookup() instead. It's not an issue here, but I usually try to avoid using Lookup() because "If the Lookup function can not find an exact match, it chooses the largest value in the lookup_range that is less than or equal to the value."

Comment: I use OFFSET in combination with MATCH instead of VLOOKUP whenever I can, it's a lot more powerful. I can't stand the syntax of VLOOKUP, with the arbitrary number of columns etc - and if you insert or delete a column it breaks. If you use OFFSET(column_header,MATCH(reference_value,reference_column,0),0) then it is robust against that, and you get the benefit of being able to use any sorting order. LOOKUP breaks if you don't sort your data, VLOOKUP breaks if you add/remove columns...

Comment: +1 to Richard. I haven't tried it, but it sounds like a great alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way you can do this with pivot tableS - one per role. It's a bit dubious whether you should, but depends how many roles you have really. I made it work using 2 as a sample, here's the gist:

- You have an (Excel) table containing Names
- You have an (Excel) table containing Meeting Date, RoleA, RoleB... (I used Chair and Secretary as nominal examples), these cells contain the name of the person taking that role

You then create a Pivot Table for each role (Insert --> Pivot Table). The fields to use are: Row Labels - whichever role you're analysing; Values - Meeting Date

You then change the result type by going into Field Settings, and change it to Minimum. Note that only people who have had that role will show up here.

Repeat this for each role.

Go back to your table of names, and add a column for each role to show when they last held the role. The formula for this is the rather unwieldy:

```
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Meeting Date",Chair!$A$3,"Chair",People[[#This Row],[Name]]),0)
```

The GETPIVOTDATA will error if they haven't had that role, so I'm replacing errors with 0 (an arbitrary low number)

You can then identify the person most overdue for the role using:

```
=OFFSET(People[[#Headers],[Name]],MATCH(MIN(People[LastChair]),People[LastChair],0),0)
```

If there is a tie, the person who appears first in your list of names will be given here.

Hope that makes some semblance of sense, ask away if any questions

Comment: Thanks for the response, and the email!  It looks like I can get the results I need (and make things easier for the next person who inherits this spreadsheet) by skipping Pivots *and* VBA and using pure formulas.  However, while I put the green-checkmark on PowerUser's answer, I'm also giving an upvote to this one because it was very helpful in general.  Learning about Field Settings was the "ah ha!" moment I was waiting for... at first it looked like PivotTables were good for nothing but counting sums.

Comment: No probs Steve, glad it's got you into Pivot Tables, they are powerful things! Have an explore some time, they can do all sorts.